# Как включить React Fiber?

Tags: reactjs

Хочу включить React Fiber, как его включить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

===

```
npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental
```

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Раньше вы использовали:
//
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
//
// Теперь для перехода в конкурентный режим нужно написать:

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root')
).render(<App />);
```

Источник https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите из текста по ссылке основное в ответ. Ответы из одной ссылки не допускаются на so, т.к. могут протухать, меняться пути и т.п.